# SQL/NewSQL suited read only, OLAP Database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, olap

I am looking for a sql/newsql database Engine which is suited for fast Response times on a read only Star Schema for ad-hoc olap purposes. Complete dataset is about 4 Billion rows and MySql ist performing very slow on that Task.

I would be very grateful for some recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a read only star schema benchmark, try MariaDB Columnstore. It is very fast with data load and star schema-like queries.

Answer (score 1):

[Hive](https://hive.apache.org/)

"The Apache Hive ™ data warehouse software facilitates reading,
writing, and managing large datasets residing in distributed storage
using SQL. Structure can be projected onto data already in storage. A
command line tool and JDBC driver are provided to connect users to
Hive."